# Android broadcast not received from widget

Tags: java, android

I Have a widget that upon button press I send broadcast to service. But I am not receving any broadcast in my `onReceive()`.

My intention is basically on widget button click, it tellls service to perform some action. 
But I am unable to receive any broadcast from widget in service.

Here is my widget code -

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName componentName;

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        componentName = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.play,getPendingSelfIntent(context, "PLAY",componentName));

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(componentName, remoteViews);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName componentName;

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        componentName = new ComponentName(context, MyService.class);

        if (intent.getAction().equals("PLAY")) {
            Log.d("hi","PLAY0");
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.engine_lock_unlock,getPendingSelfIntent(context,"PLAY",componentName));
            serviceIntent = new Intent(context,MyService.class);

            serviceIntent.setAction("PLEASE_PLAY");
            Log.d("hi","PLAY1");
            context.sendBroadcast(serviceIntent);
        }


        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(componentName, remoteViews);
    }

    protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action, ComponentName componentName) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
        intent.setAction(action);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, componentName);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    }
```

In MyService,

```
public class ServiceWidgetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("hi","PLAY2");

            if (intent.getAction().equals("PLEASE_PLAY")) {

            }
      }
}
```

My MAnifest looks like this -

```
<receiver android:name=".widget.MyWidgetProvider" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
               android:resource="@xml/homescreen_widget_preview" />
</receiver>
<receiver android:name=".service.MyService$ServiceWidgetReceiver" />
```

I only get the logs -

```
PLAY0
PLAY1
```

Why I dont get my broadcast???

Answer (score 0):

Seams that your receiver has no intent-filter provided. Try to add this in your mainfest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".service.MyService$ServiceWidgetReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="PLEASE_PLAY" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have implement the action in intent-filter like Myon said, but the still no broadcast to the onReceive. you may try this:

```
protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action, ComponentName componentName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    intent.setAction(action);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, componentName);

    //this line replace the original
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Actually, i have facing the similar problem yesterday that my widget work fine on my android 5.1 phone. However, I find it cannot perform click on android 7.0 sony phone. I still trying to find out whether is the sony phone os problem or android 7.0 or after problem because after the upgrade of the 7.0 or after, there is so many different issues appeared as they changed quite a lot in the API. Anyway, I used the PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT solved the problem I have on 7.0

I just think will directly register the receiver class to manifest like this be work. The service binded doesnt directly affect the receive, as the only thing affect the receiver is context. So, maybe just the receive class is enough.

```
<receiver android:name="packageName.ServiceWidgetReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="PLEASE_PLAY" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Still doesnt work :( I think for your problem with Android 7, broadcast receiver must be registered on unregistered in onCreate and onDestroy rather than in Manifest

Comment: Actually, I just use the pending intent for the onclick method. As it is not an extra service, I think the way to register UI component on the onUpdate is a recommended way. Btw, is the log you put newest is come from the line of Log.d("hi","PLAY0"); and Log.d("hi","PLAY1"); ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the mistake I was doing. I had to registerreceiver and unregister it in Service itself rather in Manifest.
This worked for me.